# Ошибка линковки проекта c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ассемблер

Писал программу для перевода чисел из DEC в HEX и наоборот разными функциями на Windows с помощью MVS, теперь пришла пора перенести программу на линукс, однако я встретился с неразрешимой проблемой.

/usr/bin/ld: ./Source.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `n' can not be used when making a PIE object; перекомпилируйте с параметром -fPIC
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Компилировать через консоль с параметром -fPIC проблвал, не помогло, в настройках проекта параметр указывал.

Кстати изначально программа была написана для х32 версии|, ещё на винде, а здесь убунта х64.

Версии:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS х64

g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200

Выкладываю код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum
{
   CMD_FLOAT_TO_HEX,
   CMD_DOUBLE_TO_HEX,
   CMD_HEX_TO_FLOAT,
   CMD_HEX_TO_DOUBLE,
   CMD_EXIT
};

template<typename in, typename out>
out Asm1(in n)  // FLOAT / DOUBLE -> HEX
{
   out res;
   asm
   (
      "fld n;"
      "fstp res;"
   );
   return res;
}

template<typename in, typename out>
out Asm2(in n)  // HEX -> FLOAT / DOUBLE
{
   out res;
   asm
   (
      "movsd %xmm0, n;"
      "movsd res, %xmm0;"
   );
   return res;
}

template<typename in, typename out>
out Memcpy(in n)
{
   out res;
   memcpy(&res, &n, sizeof(in));
   return res;
}

template<typename in, typename out>
out Cast(in n)
{
   return *reinterpret_cast<out*>(&n);
}

template<typename in, typename out>
out Union(in n)
{
   union
   {
      in _n;
      out _res;
   };
   _n = n;
   return _res;
}


int main()
{
   int n;

   cout << "<0> - float to hex" << endl;
   cout << "<1> - double to hex" << endl;
   cout << "<2> - hex to float" << endl;
   cout << "<3> - hex to double" << endl;
   cout << "<4> - exit" << endl << endl;
   do
   {
      cout << "choose command (from 0 to 4): ";
      cin >> n;
      cout << endl;
      switch (n)
      {
      case CMD_FLOAT_TO_HEX:
         float f1;
         cout << "write a number: ";
         cin >> f1;

         cout << "\na float number " << f1 << " in hex:\t0x"   << hex << Memcpy<float, int>(f1) << " (MEMCPY)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t0x"                                  << hex << Cast<float, int>(f1)   << " (REINTERPRETER_CAST)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t0x"                                  << hex << Union<float, int>(f1)  << " (UNION)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t0x"                                  << hex << Asm1<float, int>(f1)   <<  " (__ASM) "<<endl;
         cout << endl;
         break;
      case CMD_DOUBLE_TO_HEX:
         double d1;
         cout << "write a number: ";
         cin >> d1;

         cout << "\na double number " << d1 << " in hex:\t0x"  << hex << Memcpy<double, long long>(d1) << " (MEMCPY)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t0x"                                  << hex << Cast<double, long long>(d1)   << " (REINTERPRETER_CAST)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t0x"                                  << hex << Union<double, long long>(d1)  << " (UNION)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t0x"                                  << hex << Asm1<double, long long>(d1)   << " (__ASM) " << endl;
         cout << endl;
         break;
      case CMD_HEX_TO_FLOAT:
         uint32_t f2;
         cout << "write a hex: ";
         cin >> hex >> f2;

         cout << "\na hex 0x" << hex << f2 << " is equal to float\t"   << Memcpy<int, float>(f2) << " (MEMCPY)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t\t"                                          << Cast<int, float>(f2)   << " (REINTERPRETER_CAST)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t\t"                                          << Union<int, float>(f2)  << " (UNION)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t\t"                                          << Asm2<int, float>(f2)   << " (__ASM) " << endl;
         cout << endl;
         break;
      case CMD_HEX_TO_DOUBLE:
         uint64_t d2;
         cout << "write a hex: ";
         cin >> hex >> d2;

         cout << "\na hex 0x" << hex << d2 << " is equal to double\t"  << Memcpy<long long, double>(d2) << " (MEMCPY)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                        << Cast<long long, double>(d2)   << " (REINTERPRETER_CAST)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                        << Union<long long, double>(d2)  << " (UNION)" << endl;
         cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                        << Asm2<long long, double>(d2)   << " (__ASM) " << endl;
         cout << endl;
         break;
      case CMD_EXIT:
         break;
      default:
         cout << "wrong command" << endl;
         cout << endl;
         break;
      }
   } while (n != CMD_EXIT);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ассемблерные вставки — вещь не стандартная, так что при переносе на другой компилятор их надо переписать. Синтаксис оных на gcc сильно отличается от msvc. Подробности можно посмотреть в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCC_Inline_Assembly) или в [доках](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: Ну я таки переписал, на ассемблерные вставки компилятор не ругается

Comment: `"movsd %xmm0, n;"` - А кто вам сказал, что так можно? Почему вы решили, что можно вот так напрямую использовать имена локальных переменных в ассемблере?

Comment: то что компилятор проглотил это ещё не значит, что это что-то осмысленное;)... во-первых, в базовом варианте ассемблера gcc ни как не анализирует содержимое и просто вставляет указанные строки в листинг. во-вторых, в расширенном режиме он проводит только самые простые подстановки, но при этом gas явно делает различие между командами разного размера, так что использовать подобные шаблоны на практике не получится... в-третьих, по умолчанию gas ожидает at&t синтаксис команд, а в этом случае порядок регистров должен быть другой...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ассемблер в GCC так не работает.

Ассемблер в GCC не поддерживает прямого обращения к локальным переменным по именам. Всякий раз, когда вы пишете что-то вроде `"fld n;"`, компилятор рассматривает это как обращение к *глобальной* переменной `n` и передает его на рассмотрение линкеру. Линкер, разумеется, не находит никакой глобальной переменной `n`, что и приводит к ошибке.

Локальные переменные нужно вручную описывать в ассемблерном блоке как входные и выходные операнды, через специальный синтаксис. См. пример [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359092/intel-asm-syntax-with-gcc-undefined-reference) и документацию [здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Например

```
float Asm1(double n)
{
   float res;
   asm 
   (
      "fldl %1;"
      "fstps %0;"
      : "=m" (res) : "m" (n) 
   );
   return res;
}
```

При этом надежды на то, что в вашем исходном варианте ассемблерный код с `fld` и `fstp` поведет себя "по шаблонному" и будет генерировать правильную команду для каждого размера операнда не оправдались. В ассемблере GCC `fld` и `fstp` просто тупо эквивалентны `flds` и `fstps`. Для того, чтобы ваш шаблон с параметрами `Asm1<double, float>` работал правильно, придется все равно явно указывать `fldl`, как у меня в примере выше. То есть вся ваша затея с таким ассемблерным кодом внутри шаблона - не работает.